# Upload directory into folder within bucket using javascript S3

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm using the [node-s3-client](https://github.com/andrewrk/node-s3-client) library to upload files to my bucket.

I have a local folder, `/build`, that I would like to upload to a folder within an S3 bucket, entitled `Library`.

Placing individual files into the Library folder is easy:

```
const params = {
  localFile: './individualFile',
  s3Params: {
    Bucket: config.aws.s3Bucket,
    Key: 'Library/individualFile',
  }
}

const uploader = client.uploadFile(params); // works great!
```

However, I'm not sure how to configure the params to upload the contents of a *directory* into a folder within a bucket. I've tried this:

```
const params = {
  localDir: './build',
  s3Params: {
    Bucket: config.aws.s3Bucket,
    Key: 'Library/',
  }
}

const uploader = client.uploadDir(params); // doesn't work :(
```

The upload is successful, but the contents end up at the root of the bucket rather than inside the folder. In other words, the `Key` feature doesn't seem to work when it comes to directories.

Comment: Have you tried using a loop to get all files in folder and concatenate file name at `Key`?

Comment: I'd prefer I didn't have to resort to that, but great idea nonetheless. I'll do that for now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `Prefix` instead of `Key`:

```
const params = {
  localDir: './build',
  s3Params: {
    Bucket: config.aws.s3Bucket,
    Prefix: 'Library/'
  }
}
```